# How to print out a double value without losing first digit

Tags: c++, double, cin, cout

When I run my code, it only prints the decimal parts of the double. On another page, I took a inputted double and printed out the double the way it was inputted.
But for my following code, it only prints out the decimals. For example, when I input 1.95 it only prints out 0.95. Why is it removing the first digit? I see nothing in my code that points to this.

I have already tried it in a more simple way and it worked. And I dont see any problems that would mess with the double in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double price;
char user_input;
do
{
    cout << "Enter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ";
    cin >> user_input;
    if (user_input == 'q')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cin >> price;
        int multiple = price * 100;
        if (multiple % 5 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Illegal price: Must be a non-negative multiple of 5 cents.\n" << endl;
        }
    }
} while (user_input != 'q');

cout << price << endl;
}
```

When I input 1.95, I get 0.95. But the output should be 1.95.

Comment: You should print out `user_input`'s value to get a big hint.

Comment: you might want to read the entire line into a string and parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem covered in other answer: Reading for the `'q'` removed the first character from the stream before it could be parsed into a `double`.

A solution: Read the `double` first. If the read fails, check to see if the input is a `'q'`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double price;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ";
        if (cin >> price)
        {
            // use price
        }
        else // reading price failed. Find out why.
        {
            if (!cin.eof()) // didn't hit the end of the stream
            {
                // clear fail flag
                cin.clear();
                char user_input;
                if (cin >> user_input && user_input == 'q') // test for q
                {
                    break; // note: Not return. Cannot print price if the
                           // program returns
                }
                // Not a q or not readable. clean up whatever crap is still
                // in the stream
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            else

            {
                // someone closed the stream. Not much you can do here but exit
                cerr << "Stream closed or broken. Cannot continue.";
                return -1;

            }
        }
    }

    cout << price << endl;// Undefined behaviour if price was never set.
}
```

Another reasonable alternative is to read all input as `std::string`. If the `string` is not `"q"`, attempt to convert it to a `double` with `std::stod` or an `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

When you type 1.95 in the command line, variable `user_input` gets assigned '1', and `price` gets assigned .95.

Comment: How could I stop it from doing that? Shouldnt it skip the user_input since I didnt input a q?

Comment: @JohnDoe `cin >> price;` and check for failure. If it fails, check to see if the input was a `q`.

Comment: Is there any way to compare a double and a character? Like can I use if (price == 'q')?

Comment: @JohnDoe You could read all input as `string`, test the `string` for "q", and attempt to turn the `string` into a `double` if the `string` is not "q".